# cakephp - view with data from multiple tables as one

Tags: cakephp, model, behavior

I want to have a view for each table (letters, filings, notes) which each have a name and date.  I want to have a separate view for items from each table that also fall into a particular category -- say categoryx -- so it is a separate view.  The categoryx view would combine particular fields from each of the multiple tables into one table, in effect, ordered by date.

E.g.,

```
Category x

DATE       NAME          ORIGTABLE
1/2/11     SmithToJones  Letters
1/3/11     Filing on X   Filings
1/4/11     Note re X     Notes
1/7/11     JonesToSmith  Letters
```

I'm just stumped on whether there is a good or straightforward way to do this.  Open to options.  Thanks

Comment: How are you assigning categories to items? Are there relational tables?  Just a "category" field of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer, though it's not perfect.  I do this in the controller (may try it in the model next):

```
$query='select name,date, "letters" as "origtable" from letters
UNION SELECT name,date, "filings" as "origtable" from filings 
UNION SELECT name,date, "notes" as "origtable" from notes
ORDER BY date';

$things=$this->Letter->query($query);
$this->set('items',$things);
```

This gets me an array I can parse out.  If I add id to it, then I can easily create links to the relevant item in the relevant table.